# how to write image data to a text file as a base 64 string?

Tags: java, android, image, base64

im trying to write image data to a text file as a base 64 string its working if it doesnt contain to much information but when it contains quite a bit of information it crashes the application saying that its out off memory below is my code:

```
package com.search.visual;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String>{
    String name;
    byte[] num;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),".vis/image.xml");

    name = Base64.encodeToString(params[0], 0);



    //return base64String;
    if (photo.exists()){
        photo.delete();
    }
    try{



        FileWriter fi = new FileWriter(photo.getPath());
        fi.write("<Image>\n\t<Data>");
        fi.write(name);

        fi.write("</Data>\n</Image>");
        fi.close();


    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("pictureDemo","exception", e);
    }


    return (null);
}

    }
```

am i doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're simply running out of RAM.  One reason this is happening is because you're holding the entire original image and the entire base-64 encoded image in memory, all at once, even if only briefly.  Try writing the data out a chunk at a time in a for loop, using the variation:

```
encodeToString(byte[] input, int offset, int len, int flags)
```

And encoding and writing a few thousand bytes at a time

Comment: I tried that code and it seems to be working havent yet tried decoding it yet but it is writing the file instantly and a lot smaller than my original files and is writing instantaneous.

Comment: I'm not sure the file should be smaller by the end, you still want to write all of the data, just in smaller chunks.

Comment: when i look at the file it seems to have the same amount of lines as when i was previously doing it. this is the for loop ive written 

    for(int i = 0; i<params.length; i++){
     name = Base64.encodeToString(params[0], 0, 1024, 0);//method mentiond in blog i chose to split it into bytes of 1024 each time
     
     fi.append(name);
    }

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  You're writing the first 1024 bytes over and over again.  I would turn the variable i into a byte counter.  Increment it by however many bytes each chunk is (1024, in your case), and pass it back in as the offset parameter.

Comment: so if i increments by 1024 each time and pass i to the offset that should work?

Comment: Give it a shot, and let me know!

Comment: i tried it and it  worked but i now have a new  problem which  is that i either run out of memory before its finished or my array isnt long enough to finish

Comment: hey Ive got it working at last I just changed the picture resolution and im able to write the image in one line. thank you for all the help you offered though it was greatly appreciated.